# Как объединить две таблицы и вызвать результат через PHP

Tags: php, mysql

А кто подскажет, как сделать такую выборку из таблиц ?

У меня таблицы :

1- объекты недвижимости, в котором есть столбец city и в нем id города

2- города, где у каждого города есть столбик id и столбик city

Как мне на PHP вызвать через echo название города так, что бы он совпадал с объектом недвижимости ?

Что-то типа `<?php echo $row->agent_name;?>` только вместо "agent_namе" что бы было что либо, что выводило бы название города ? Так как заменяя "agent_name" на "city" я получаю id города, а мне нужно название города...

Спасибо за отзывы...

Answer (score 0):

Вы не привели пример того, как вы получаете данные из БД в php. Если в 1-й таблице в city хранится id города, то это желательно должен быть внешний ключ на поле id 2-й таблицы.

```
$db = mysqli_connect(
'localhost', /* Хост, к которому мы подключаемся */
'root', /* Имя пользователя */
'', /* Используемый пароль */
'BD');
//1 и 2 - ваши названия таблиц
$que = "SELECT 2.city FROM 2 INNER JOIN 1 ON 1.city=2.id WHERE 1.id = ?";
$sel = $db->prepare($que);
$sel->bind_param("i", $idCity);//Здесь биндим id города из 1-й таблицы
$sel->execute();
$sel->store_result();
$sel->bind_result($city);
$sel->fetch();
echo "Город $city";
```